My form validation isnt working, issue with the JS or html. for uni work
I tried to keep it simple but not sure what's wrong. I'm not sure if the return command is working or not, the button might be messing it up but not sure.
I'm new to HTML and JS and my tutor was unable to help. I've double read everything but still cant find anything conclusive. Any help would be great thanks.


function validatebookclass() {

  var accountname = document.getElementById("username");
  var accountpassword = document.getElementById("password");
  var coursetype = document.getElementById("ctype");
  var numberofattendees = document.getElementById("numb");
  var date = document.getElementById("date");
  var timeselect = document.getElementById("time");
  var ingredientsdelivered = document.getElementById("ingd");
  var dietry = document.getElementById("diet");

  if (accountname.value == "" || accountpassword.value == "" || coursetype.value == "" || numberofattendees.value == "select" ||
    date.value == "" || timeselect.value == "pick" || ingredientsdelivered.value == "" || dietry.value == "") {

    alert("Please fill in all fields");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Thank you for booking.");
    true;
  }
}
<form name="bookclass" onsubmit="return validatebookclass()" method="post">

  <h id="ftitle"> Username:</h>
  <input type="text" name="username" size="30" placeholder="Enter username here...">

  <label for="password"> Password:</label>
  <input type="Password" name="password" size="30" placeholder="Enter password here..."><br><br>

  <label for="ctype"> Course Type:</label><br> Introductory
  <input type="radio" name="ctype" value="introct"><br> Amateur <input type="radio" name="ctype" value="amact"><br> Professional <input type="radio" name="ctype" value="proct"><br><br>

  <label for="numb"> Number of attendees:</label> <br>
  <select name="numb">
    <option value="select">Select</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="Two">two</option>
  </select>

  <br><br>

  <label for="date"> Time Slot:</label><br>
  <input type="date" name="date">
  <select name="time">
    <option value="pick">Select</option>
    <option value="10am-1pm">10am-1pm</option>
    <option value="11am-2pm">11am-2pm</option>
    <option value="12pm-3pm">10am-1pm</option>
    <option value="1pm-4pm">11am-2pm</option>
    <option value="2pm-5pm">10am-1pm</option>
  </select>

  <br><br>

  <label for="ingd"> Ingredients delivered:</label><br> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="ingd" value="yes"> No
  <input type="radio" name="ingd" value="no"><br>

  <p id="bclass">If yes, you will be emailed with a further form to fill out.</p>

  <label for="diet">Dietry Restrictions:</label><br> Gluten Free<input type="checkbox" name="diet" value="gf"> Nut-free <input type="checkbox" name="diet" value="nf"> <br> dairy-free
  <input type="checkbox" name="diet" value="df"> Other <input type="checkbox" name="diet" value="other"><br> None <input type="checkbox" name="diet" value="none">

  <br>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>




Can you describe what is happening?  Does the function execute? Are there errors in the browser console?  What are the exact values of the inputs.  Liberally use console.log in your code and run with the browser console open.

From your code above you are never returning true. You need to do return true to return it. But the alert is not happening anyway, so you don't run into that case.

in VSS it does not say there are any errors in the code. When I submit the form it refreshes the page even when false, and no alerts pop up. Not sure how to use the console log.

The first job when debugging JS is to open the console (F12) and check for errors. When you do this and submit the form you can see the error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value'). This is because you are attempting to retrieve the input elements from the DOM by their id, but none of them actually have id attributes

It's not quite getting that far (there's no alert - referring to the missing return in front of true).  Copying to a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5L0wusnj/ gives Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Also, I know this is for coursework, but you can make this much simpler and more reliable by using the required attribute in your HTML instead.

return true didnt fix the code, the form still doesnt work.

Open page in browser, press F12, select console, click the settings (cog in the top right), make sure preserve log is ticked.  Click submit on your page.

Cool thank you ill investigate further.

Label for can only be used for one element at a time and IDs need to be unique

Your JavaScript is trying to get elements by their id, but your form elements use the name attribute instead of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
Change the name attributes to Add id attributes in your HTML to match the IDs used in the JavaScript
Or you can use getElementsByName https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName
Also in else block you forgot about return

Just FYI, you need to keep the name attributes for the key/value pairs to be encoded correctly in the request that's sent. Removing or changing them to id is not a viable solution

of course, you can use at the same time id and name attributes
